# HttpsURLConnection not working with API 28 Android 9

Tags: android

SSLPeerUnverifiedException happening :

```
HttpsURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
// do other works
httpURLConnection.connect();//its happening here
```

Comment: I tried to amend my network configuration file, as below but still facing same issue :

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">aramex.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">sa.aramex.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>

Comment: You might want to include which HTTPS resource(s) you were trying to access, as this could be related to the problem.

Comment: it's a web service that is located under one of our local servers to check if the one who is trying to access our App, has the needed privilege or he has not.

Comment: Sorry for that, but I forget mentioning that its working fine with Android 8 and older versions